# Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to update bigint field with nvarchar field . So, I write this query .

```
update table1 
set convert(bigint,table1.No)=convert(bigint,substring(table_2.Desc,21,50))
from table1
inner join table_2 on table1.ID=table_2.ID
```

SQL Server shows an error like that  "Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.
". How can I fix this problem? Anybody help me ,please .

Comment: You can not update expression. Also the `substring(table_2.Desc,21,50)` returns non-convertable result on any row.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CONVERT` expression on the left-hand side of the `SET` is unnecessary. You should do just

```
update table1
set table1.[No]=convert(bigint,substring(table_2.[Desc],21,50))
from table1
inner join table_2 on table1.ID=table_2.ID
```

The “Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.” error message means the expression inside `convert` cannot be converted to a bigint, probably because it is not a properly formatted number. Are you sure your `21,50` arguments are correct? Are you aware the last argument to [`substring`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) should be *the length* of the substring, not the index of the end character? Try calling

```
select substring(table_2.[Desc],21,50) from table_2
```

to see what you are trying to use as numbers.